# Selecting a sentence in mysql starting with a word, and NOT followed by another word

Tags: php, mysql, regex, database, mysqli

I'm trying to select a sentence in mysql starting with the word 'by' and NOT followed by the word 'the', but it's not working somehow. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `allData` 
WHERE response REGEXP  '^by ?!the'
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

Comment: Argh, that's right. No greedy characters, like `?` allowed in MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql regex doesn't support positive or negative lookeaheads. alternatively you could do something like

```
response REGEXP  '^by ' and response not like 'by the%'
```